# Updating the dictionary in the for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary

I have such code, dictionary x must be created outside the loop for:

```
one = [1,3,3,4,5,6]
x = {'x': {}, 'a': 1}
t = []
for i in one:
    x['x'] = {'z': i}
    t.append(x)
```

Why i`m getting this:

```
[{'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 6}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 6}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 6}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 6}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 6}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 6}}]
```

I hope to have this:

```
[{'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 1}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 3}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 3}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 4}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 5}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 6}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are actually modifying the same `x` object in your loop, so they all point to the same object. That is why all values of `z` in the dictionary have the last value.

You could use the following list comprehension

```
t = [{'x': {'z': i}, 'a':1} for i in one]
```

Output

```
>>> t
[{'x': {'z': 1}, 'a': 1},
 {'x': {'z': 3}, 'a': 1},
 {'x': {'z': 3}, 'a': 1},
 {'x': {'z': 4}, 'a': 1},
 {'x': {'z': 5}, 'a': 1},
 {'x': {'z': 6}, 'a': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a single `x` object you're modifying and re-appending to `t`. In other words, this line: `x['x'] = {'z': i}` does not create a new object, it modifies it. After the loop the list is holding six references to the same single object.

Answer (score 0):

```
one = [1,3,3,4,5,6]

t = []
for i in one:
    t.append({'x': {'z': i}, 'a': 1}) # new/dict object each iteration
print(t)

[{'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 1}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 3}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 3}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 4}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 5}}, {'a': 1, 'x': {'z': 6}}]
```